# Write a Fizz program in assembly / Using C library

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, nasm, calling-convention

Could someone help me with this assembly program: First print out numbers 1 to 100. Then follow the rules for the children's counting game Fizz: whenever the number is evenly divisible by 5, or contains the
digit 5, replace the number by the word “Fizz”. This is my program so far:

```
extern printf
section .data
msg db "Hello, world!",0xa
len equ $ - msg
fmt: db "a=%d, eax=%d", 10, 0 ; The printf format, "\n",'0'
section .text
global main
main:
L1:
    mov eax,1
    push eax
    call printf
    cmp eax,100
    jae end
    inc eax
end:
```

Comment: Please don't use an image for your code. Paste your code directly into your question, highlight it, and click on the `{}` just above the area where you edit the question.

Comment: You've outlined what you want the end result to be. But you haven't mentioned what the _problem_ is. That is, what specifically is stopping you from getting the desired end result? Vague descriptions like _"it doesn't work"_, or open-ended questions like _"can you help me write this"_ are not suitable for StackOverflow.

Comment: step 1: design algorithm.  step 2: implement in assembly.  step 3: debug until it works.  Using a debugger (like gdb) is essential.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to give you a complete answer since this appears to be homework. I'll provide enough to get you started. The following code will simply count from 1 to 100:

```
extern printf
section .data
fmt: db "number = %d", 10, 0 ; printf format string

section .text
global main
main:
    push ebx      ; EBX is callee saved so we need to save it so that it 
                  ;     can be restored when we RETurn from main
    mov ebx, 1    ; ebx = 1 (counter)
L1:
    push ebx      ; 2nd parameter is our number(counter) to print
    push fmt      ; 1st parameter is the address of the format string
    call printf
    add sp, 8     ; We pushed 8 bytes prior to printf call, we must adjust the stack
                  ;     by effectively removing those bytes.
    inc ebx       ; counter += 1
    cmp ebx,100
    jle L1        ; If counter is <= 100 go back and print again
end:
    xor eax,eax   ; Return 0 when our program exits
    pop ebx       ; Restore EBX before exiting main per calling convention
    ret           ; RETurn from main will cause program to gracefully exit
                  ;     because we are linked to the C runtime code and main was 
                  ;     called by that C runtime code when our program started.
```

Primary changes from your code. We display the number using [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) with a proper format string. I put the counter in *EBX* because you must be aware that *EAX*, *ECX*, and *EDX* are not preserved across a function call using [CDECL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) calling convention:

> In cdecl, subroutine arguments are passed on the stack. Integer values and memory addresses are returned in the EAX register, floating point values in the ST0 x87 register. **Registers EAX, ECX, and EDX are caller-saved, and the rest are callee-saved.**
>
> [snip]
>
> The caller cleans the stack after the function call returns.

After making *CDECL* function calls, we must restore the stack pointer. We push 2 *DWORD*s (a total of 8 bytes) as parameters to `printf` therefore we must add 8 to the stack pointer to *effectively* remove them when the function returns.

The highlighted sentence is important. To simplify things I use *EBX* because its value is preserved across function calls and we don't have to save and restore it around the function calls we make (like `printf`).

Since `main` is being called as a *C* function using *CDECL* calling convention, we must preserve any callee registers (registers our function must preserve) so that we don't cause undefined behavior in the *C* library code that calls `main`. *EBX* is a callee saved register we did modify, so we use *PUSH*/*POP* around our function so that *EBX* is preserved when our `main` function returns.

The program has to be linked to a *C* library. The easiest way to do this is to link with *GCC*. The compile and link stage could look like:

```
nasm -f elf32 count100.asm -o count100.o
gcc -m32 count100.o -o count100
```

This should assemble and link your code to a 32-bit program called `count100` that can be executed with this command:

```
./count100
```

I leave the rest of the assignment up to you.

---

The assembly code in the sample would be equivalent to this code in *C*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int counter = 1;
    do {
        printf ("number = %d\n", counter);
    } while (++counter <= 100);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `main` returns, rather than calling `exit`, so you need to save/restore the caller's `ebx` to make sure the CRT code that called `main` doesn't crash.  Reasonable compromise in showing a working loop without completely doing the OP's homework for them, though.

Comment: @PeterCordes : chuckle you caught me on that one. The first version I wrote did call `exit` and so I didn't bother. Before I posted I changed to a _ret_ when it was clear this was being linked to the _C_ library anyway. Thanks. I amended the code a bit.