# Assembly Program: Game of Fizz

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

This assembly program is a Fizz game. It should follow the rules for the children's counting game Fizz: It should print from 1-100 and whenever the number is evenly divisible by 5, or contains the digit 5, replace the number by the word “Fizz”.

I'm currently having issue with this program. The program runs but the output is:
number = 1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
I would appreciate if someone can help me on this. Thanks

```
    enter cextern printf
section .data
fmt: db "number = %d", 10, 0 ; printf format string
fmt2: db " %s",10,0
fmt3: db " %s ", 10, 0
section .text
global main
main:
    push ebx      ; EBX is callee saved so we need to save it so that it
                  ; it can be restored when we RETurn from main
    xor ecx,ecx  ; ebx = 0 (counter)
L1:
    inc ecx
    xor eax,eax
    mov eax,ecx
    xor ebx,ebx
    xor edx,edx
    mov ebx,5
    idiv ebx
    cmp edx,0
    jz Fizz
    push ecx      ; 2nd parameter is our number to print
    push fmt      ; 1st parameter is the address of the format string
    call printf

    ;add sp, 8     ; We pushed 8 bytes prior to printf call, we must adjust the stack
                  ; by effectively removing those bytes.
           ; counter += 1
    cmp ecx,100
    jle L1        ; If counter is <= 100 go back and print again
    jmp end
Fizz:
    mov ebx,0x4669
    mov eax, 0x7A7A
    push ebx
    push eax
    push fmt2
    call printf
    pop eax
    pop ebx

    jmp L1
end:
    pop ebx       ; Restore EBX before exiting main per calling convention
    ret           ; RETurn from main will cause program to gracefully exit
                  ;     because we are linked to the C runtime code and main was
                  ;     called by that C runtime code when our program started.ode here
```

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger and seeing where it crashes?

Comment: Something about this [looks familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36092926/3857942)

Comment: @micheal Petch, yea it crashes at 0x080482 in ?? (). when I do the info registers, this is what it gives me: eax            0x0  0
ecx            0x1  1
edx            0x1  1
ebx            0x5  5
esp            0xffffd810   0xffffd810
ebp            0x0  0x0
esi            0x1  1
edi            0xf7fb3000   -134533120
eip            0xf7ff06c1   0xf7ff06c1 <_dl_runtime_resolve+1>
eflags         0x202    [ IF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x63 99
(gdb)

Comment: _ECX_ will be trashed by the call to _printf_, the add `esp, 8` you have commented out will not end well once your `main` function does the `ret`. Not sure what you are trying to do with the call to printf that uses `fmt2`. _EAX_ will be treated as a pointer, but you have loaded it with a garbage (0x7a7a) address so printf will likely fail to what you expect (or crash)

Comment: So what would you recommend me to do here?

Comment: Why are you placing character literals in `eax` and `ebx`? Just declare the string `"Fizz",10,0` in the data section and use that.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is crashing because you are not account for `ECX` changing during a function call and you have unbalanced push/pop going on. Notice here:

```
push ecx
push fmt
call printf
```

but you never `pop` those two values back off of the stack. Since `ECX` is not preserved in the call and you perform no other operations after the function returns, you are relying on whatever `ECX` happen to be after the function call.

If you have a look at the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions), you'll find that `ecx` is not preserved on function calls. You may find it unchanged, but you can't depend on this. You must preserve it.

This is leading the code to immediately jump to `end` and try to `ret`. This will *immediately* crash because you are now trying to return to the address of the format string since that's what's next on the stack.

Perhaps this?

```
push ecx
push fmt
call printf
pop ecx  ; fmt
pop ecx  ; ECX
cmp ecx, 100
jle end
```

Comment: ok, I have changed it to the one you said, and when I run it is printing numbers 1 to 4 then gives a segmentation fault (core dumped). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Apply the same principles to the other unbalanced push/pop combinations that you have in the code. I noticed at least one other unbalanced set.

Comment: Could you tell which one specifically?

Comment: Could you tell me how would I fix this whole  program please? Thanks

Comment: No. This is clearly a class assignment... I've given you more than enough to get you most of the way there as evidenced by the code being more functional now. Look at where you are pushing three things and popping only two.

Comment: Ok, I have changed fmt2: db "fizz", 10,0 in the data section and I have commented out the move ebx, 0x4669 and move eax,07a7a. Also, in the Fizz: I have 4 pushes: ebx, eax, fmt2, fmt2 and 4 pops eax, eax, ebx, ebx. and the result im getting now is that it prints numbers 1 -4 only and then it prints Fizz and it countinues to do 1-4 over and over again

Comment: Sounds like progress. Work through the debugging process and think about things. You're making it through 1 to 4 and then it resets... So, something must be clearing ECX. What happens when ECX is 4 or 5? Walk through the code by hand and look at it. Even better, run the code under a debugger and step through when ECX = 4 and 5 and see what happens!