# Printf displays garbage values

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, nasm, libc

```
section .data

    array dw  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10   ; array of integers
    msg db " numbers are :  %d %d ",10,0

section .text 

global main
extern printf   ; for c printf

main: 

    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp     ;intialise stack

    mov ax,11
    push ax        ;push ax with value 11

    mov ax,22
    push ax      ;push ax with value 12
    push msg
    call printf     ; calling printf function

    add esp ,12

    mov esp,ebp     ;restore stack
    pop ebp
```

When I pushed immediate values instead of pushing via *AX* it works fine. Why is that?

Comment: can you give us an example of what your code looks like, which is failing? ;)

Comment: Why are you pushing 16-bit registers when you're using `%d` (which correspond to `int`)?

Comment: Actually, you should not push 16 bit registers no matter what the format string (unless you really know what you are doing) Also, you correctly used `add esp, 12`  and that assumes you pushed 12 bytes. TL;DR: use `eax` everywhere.

Comment: It is not necessary to add *anything* to `esp` since the following instruction `mov esp,ebp` restores it anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As Jester pointed out: don't *PUSH* 16-bit values onto the stack with 32-bit code unless you know what you are doing. *AX* is a 16-bit register (lower half of the 32-bit *EAX* register). When you do:

```
push ax
```

16-bits are pushed onto the stack because *AX* is a 16-bit register. This will prevent `printf` from accessing the value properly because the data wasn't 32-bits wide. If you were to do:

```
push 11
```

you'd find this works. When *NASM* generates 32-bit code it assumes that immediate values are 32-bits wide when pushed onto the stack. That is why this scenario worked for you.

If you were to *PUSH* a 32-bit register, then a full 32-bits of data would be placed on the top of the stack. As an example:

```
push eax
```

---

It appears that your intent may be to access or traverse a *WORD* array (*WORD* = 16-bit values) and print them with the `%d` conversion specifier used by `printf`. `%d` prints 32-bit *DWORDS* as **signed** values. You will have to load them into memory as *WORD*s and convert them to *DWORDS* before you push them on the stack.

Assembly language doesn't have the concept of variables in the conventional sense of a higher level programming language. You give meaning to a memory location holding a *WORD* (16-bit value). Whether it is signed or unsigned is determined by the code you use to interact with that data.

The 386 has two instructions to help. [MOVSX](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) is used to **sign extend** a smaller operand to larger operand. This is used when you want the *SIGN* (positive or negative) to be preserved. [MOVZX](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVZX.html) is used to **zero extend** a smaller operand to a larger one. This instruction is for unsigned values and during the conversion is simply sets all the upper bits of the destination operand to zero.

As an example of this I wrote some code centered around an array of words:

```
section .data
    array dw  -1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,-32768,32767,32768
                                     ; array of integers
    arraylen equ ($-array)/2         ; number of word elements in array
    msg db " numbers are :  %d %d ",10,0

section .text

global main
extern printf          ; for c printf

main:

    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp        ; intialise stack
    push ebx           ; ebx is caller saved register. We destroy it so
                       ;     we must restore it before our function exits

    xor ebx, ebx       ; index = 0

    ; Make the equivalent of a for loop to traverse array
.loop1:
    cmp ebx, arraylen  ; We'll process all the elements of the array
    je .endloop        ; End when our index = arraylen

    movzx eax, word [array + ebx * 2] ; Use EBX as index into WORD array
                       ; zero extend 16-bit array value into 32-bit register
    push eax           ; parameter 3 = unsigned DWORD
    movsx eax, word [array + ebx * 2] ; Use EBX as index into WORD array
                       ; sign extend 16-bit array value into 32-bit register
    ; movsx eax, ax    ; The line above would have also worked this way
    push eax           ; parameter 2 = signed DWORD onto stack

    push msg           ; parameter 1 = pointer to format string
    call printf        ; calling printf function
    add esp, 12

    inc ebx            ; index += 1
    jmp .loop1         ; continue for loop

.endloop:

    pop ebx            ; Restore ebx
    mov esp,ebp        ; restore stack
    pop ebp
```

The code ensures that any of the registers (*EBX* in the code above) that are callee-saved per the [CDECL calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) are saved and restored at the beginning and end of the function. More on an explanation of that can be found in a recent [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36092926/3857942) I wrote.

I coded the equivalent of a for loop (you could have coded it as a do-while) or any other loop construct to traverse the array. I use both *MOVZX* and *MOVSX* and display the results with your `printf` format string.

**Note:** : *MOVZX* can also be done by zeroing out the destination operand and moving the source operand into the destination after. As an example:

```
movzx eax, word [array + ebx * 2]
```

Could have been coded as:

```
xor eax, eax  ; eax = 0
mov ax, word [array + ebx * 2]
```

---

One should be able to assemble and link with:

```
nasm -f elf32 testmov.asm
gcc -m32 -o testmov testmov.o
```

When run as `./testmov` the results should look like:

> ```
> numbers are :  -1 65535
> numbers are :  0 0
> numbers are :  1 1
> numbers are :  2 2
> numbers are :  3 3
> numbers are :  4 4
> numbers are :  5 5
> numbers are :  6 6
> numbers are :  7 7
> numbers are :  8 8
> numbers are :  9 9
> numbers are :  10 10
> numbers are :  -32768 32768
> numbers are :  32767 32767
> numbers are :  -32768 32768
> ```

---

If you want to print unsigned *WORD*s (16-bit values) with [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) you can use `%hu` (unsigned short), and for signed *WORD*s you can use `%hd` (signed short). Although you still have to pass in a *DWORD* for the parameters you don't need to worry about zero extending (or sign extending) since `printf` will only look at the lower 2 bytes of the *DWORD*s you pass as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can push a 16-bit register onto a 32-bit stack but printf will later pick it up as full 32-bit item from the stack anyway. That's where you get the garbage value from - the higher part of the item being picked up by printf. That's exactly your problem. So to prevent future problem, always push 32-bit item on 32-bit CPU, 64-bit item onto 64-bit CPU and so on. For an immediate, your compiler will default to 32-bit immediate so that's why your program works with immediates.